# angular2 select option select issue

Tags: angular

```
@Component({
    selector: 'filter',
    template: "<select [(ngModel)]="filterState" (change)="selected()">
<option value="">All</option>
                <option *ngFor="let s of states "   [ngValue]="s">{{ s.label}}</option>
            </select>",
});

export class FilterComponent { 
   private states = [
      {
        value: 'active',
        label: 'Active',
      },
      {
        value: 'done',
        label: 'Done',
      },
      {
        value: 'removed',
        label: 'REMOVED',
      }
    ];

  private filterState         =   '';
  selected() :void {
     //this.filterState is still the initiated value
  }
}
```

In the above case the "All" option is not shown and also whenever changing the option the ngModel it isn't updated.

Tried with value instead of ngValue , and also tried with a private filterState         =   0; but same happens here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need

```
[ngValue]=""
```

instead of mixing `value` and `[ngValue]`

`[value]="s"` won't work because `[value]` only supports strings but not objects.

Comment: Still the same problem

Comment: Can you provide a Plunker that allows to reproduce?

Comment: Yes i see the suggested method from you working great in plunker , my code is in angular rc 5 may be that causes , let me check , thanks again